# Angular.js bindToController in directive: data, binded to controller, is not available as this.foo?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created a simplest possible directive with `bindToController` syntax, which resulted in a crysis of faith due to what I've seen:

```
function foobar() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            foo: '='
        },
        template: "<div>foo = {{ vm.foo }}</div>",
        bindToController: true,
        controllerAs: "vm",
        controller: ["$scope", function($scope) {
            console.log(this); // print controller
            console.log(this.foo); // print controller attribute
        }]
    };
}
```

Now, in html I say:

```
<foobar foo="1"></foobar>
```

and in the resulting html I see my div's content as expected:

```
foo = 1
```

But in the console I see:

```
controller
    foo: 1
    __proto__: Object

undefined
```

Ugh, what? So, somehow, `foo` is seen as an attribute of controller, but it is not available as `this.foo` like ordinary object properties. How do I access and modify it then? And what's going on with those 2-way binded data?

**JSBin**: https://jsbin.com/xidepewofe/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2-way binding expect variable not value, should be:

```
<div ng-init="myvarname = 1">
  <foobar foo="myvarname"></foobar>
</div>
```

Another option is to change binding type to '@'.

In 1.6 change was introduced - by default bindings got resolved not immediately but before $onInit. So wrap your code in $onInit:

```
var vm = this;
vm.$onInit = function() {
  console.log(vm.foo);
}
```

or change setting:

```
.config(function($compileProvider){
  $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Petr. I passed my directive a variable from state controller like `<foobar foo="variable">` and `this.foo` is still undefined, so it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Wow, so when controller is collapsed, it is displayed as `{}` - empty, but when I open it, Chrome re-evaluates its attributes and they are already populated? Crazy stuff. Thank you.